# Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Ali' to data type int

Tags: sql

```
create table employee
(
    empID int check(empID>0),
    Fname varchar(50) check(Fname<7),
    Lname varchar(50),
    Salary int check (salary>0),
    Joining_Date date,
    DOB date, 

) ;
insert into employee values (5,'Ali','Murtaza', 30000, '2012-01-12','1984-01-20')
```

this table gives above mentioned error..
where as i want to have a check on Fname not to be more than 7..suggest ans please

Comment: You can edit your question and provide more details, I suggest you do so. Just posting the code is not a question. That being said, the error message is quite clear. I suggest you try with a explicit column list.

Comment: i cant get you driis..please explain

Answer (score 3):

Your check constraint is attempting to see if the string 'Ali' is less than seven.  That doesn't make sense.  The engine is attempting to convert ali to a int which it can not do.

I am guessing that your intent is to check to make sure that the fname character length is less than 7.  If that's the case, why use a `varchar(50)`?   Change it to a `varchar(7)` and drop the check.

```
fname varchar(7),
```

If you are really stuck on doing it in a check then you'd need to do it like this:

```
fname varchar(50) check(length(fname)<7),  /* depending on sql flavor */
```

If your attempting to do something else, it isn't clear by your question.

Further, depending on your sql flavor (tsql, plsql, etc.) the form of your check constraint may or may not be valid I'd recommend specifying what flavor of sql your question is referencing.

Comment: RTThomas you are helpful.. I need a little help how to alter this column now to use it like fname varcher(7)